# Apache hadoop on intellij

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, nullpointerexception

this is my first time using java and hadoop. I am trying to run a wordcount program.
I have made sure to install maven,hadoop(2.7.2), java 1.8 jdk. No error is shown in my code but when I try to run it I get this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1092)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:483)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:815)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:798)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:731)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkOneDirWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:489)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:530)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:507)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:305)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:133)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:533)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
at tn.insat.tp1.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:23)
```

Here is layout of my different classes :
[Layout of different classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnc9t.png)

**pom.xml** file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>hadoop.mapreduce</groupId>
    <artifactId>wordcount</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



</project>
```

**TokenizerMapper.java** :

```
package tn.insat.tp1;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class TokenizerMapper
        extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Mapper.Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(itr.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
}
```

**IntSumReducer.java** :

```
package tn.insat.tp1;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class IntSumReducer
        extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {

    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            System.out.println("value: "+val.get());
            sum += val.get();
        }
        System.out.println("--> Sum = "+sum);
        result.set(sum);
        context.write(key, result);
    }
}
```

**WordCount.java** :

```
package tn.insat.tp1;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);}}
```

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the stacktrace line `FilterFileSystem.mkdirs`, this is likely because arguments from `String[] args` are null. You need to edit the Run Configurations in the IDE to pass two file paths.

Otherwise, replace `args[0]` and `args[1]` with hard-coded Strings for filepaths.

Worth mentioning, no one really writes Mapreduce code like this, and rather uses frameworks like Spark or Flink, which can also be ran in IntelliJ (with much less code to do wordcount).

You should also stay up-to-date with at least Java 11 and Hadoop 3.x release